# connection-string strange error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;



namespace Iknowyourbrain
{

    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static void ClearControls(Control Parent)
        {

            if (Parent is TextBox)
            { (Parent as TextBox).Text = string.Empty; }
            else
            {
                foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls)
                    ClearControls(c);
            }
        }
        private void ExecuteInsert(string username, string password, string age, string gender, string emailaddress)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            string sql = "INSERT INTO tblRegistration (UserName, Password, Age, Gender, Email Address) VALUES "
                   + " (@UserName,@Password,@Age,@Gender,@Email Address)";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];


                param[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Char, 10);
                param[3] = new SqlParameter("@Gender", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
                param[4] = new SqlParameter("@Email Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

                param[0].Value = username;
                param[1].Value = password;
                param[2].Value = age;
                param[3].Value = gender;
                param[4].Value = emailaddress;


                for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
                }

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }



        }
        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            //sets the connection string from your web config file "ConnString" is the name of your Connection String
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConsString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                //call the method to execute insert to the database
                ExecuteInsert(
                              TxtUserName.Text,
                              TxtPassword.Text,
                              DropDownListGender.SelectedItem.Text,
                              TxtAge.Text, TxtEmailAddress.Text);
                Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
                ClearControls(Page);
            }




    }
}
```

is my code for my website so far. In my `web.config` file, I have

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConsString" connectionString="Data Source=WPHVD185022-9O0;
                             Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;
                             Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and when I tried to make a test to register an account, I got this error:

> Exception was unhandled by user code
>
> Insert Error:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Do you have permission to access the SQL Server?

Comment: im connected what do you mean do you have permisssion

Comment: You say you're connected. Connected how?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, your application cannot connect to the database specified in the connection string.

This could be a bad server or catalogue name, bad credentials (using integrated security will almost never work in production environments, and if it does you should fix that pronto), insufficient permissions, account disabled etc. It could also be that remote connections to the database are not allowed, either in general or from your location.

Bottom line, you need to be sure of your connection string and SQL server configuration.

Comment: Why would integrated security almost never work in production?  Why should it be fixed?  Integrated security is considered the most secure way to do database access, that way credentials are not stored on the web facing client.

Comment: @MystereMan Pray tell, when, in an ASP.NET application, the credentials would ever be stored on the client? They're stored in the web.config on the server only, a private, restricted file. Integrated security should be turned off/not used so as to not mistakenly use a valid user account on the server that in fact has too much control. An explicit account should be used with explicit credentials, mitigating human error at least.

Comment: The client is the web app.  It's the client of the database.  The point is that if the server is compromised, then the atacker now has access to the credentials of the database.

Comment: @MystereMan If the server is compromised and the connection is using integrated security or explicit password then that's the end, in both cases.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Having a username and password provides a number of things that merely having access to an account without knowing its credentials doesn't.  For instance, you might now be able to guess a password scheme, or you may be able to reduce a brute force process.  You may have other kinds of accounts that use the same username and password.  It's a bad idea to give an attacker more information than is absolutely necessary to run the service.

Comment: Also, an attacker may be able to access other web apps on the same server, and get access to the web.config of those accounts, and then be able to access those databases as well.

Comment: And yet another reason, suppose you have a web site administrator who does not have rights to access the databases. Well, he can view the web.configs, so now you have basically given him access to those databases, despite him not having access normally (think about accessing HR information, salaries of the executives, disciplinary information, changing peoples information, etc..).  Granted, if he's smart enough, he could install his own code that would then run under the IIS user, but if you use assembly signing that becomes more difficult. Integrated security is best practice.

Comment: @MystereMan All of this is peripheral. In the last case it's just emphasised, if someone has access to data that they shouldn't then your company has bigger problems than this. There are trade-offs, to be sure, but on the whole a self-contained app, in my experience, is better controlled and maintained. I mean you could say 'oh, and what if someone uses `sa` with integrated security?' but it would be stupid to say because it should be a deactivated account, and if it isn't then there are bigger concerns.

Comment: Microsoft recommends using Integrated security.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178375(v=vs.85).aspx `If possible, connect to an instance of SQL Server using integrated security instead of using an explicit user name and password. This helps avoid the possibility of the connection string being compromised and your user ID and password being exposed.`  Regardless of your preference, saying "fix it" is simply not correct.

Comment: @MystereMan 'Recommendations' aren't always correct. Context and practicability. They also say this: "Do not store connection strings as plain text. To help keep the connection to your database server secure". This is something I would, and do employ, hence 'private, restricted file' (using .NETs encryption mechanism - so even more so than just permissions); however even this could be used/abused by someone with access to the server.